# Help with identifying the brand of this vintage frame

Tags: identify-this-bike

Please help identify the brand of this vintage road bike frame. I am guessing it is from the late 80's to mid 90's.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Really the only distinguishing feature the frame has is the small diamond shape stamped on the frame joint .

Comment: The reason why I think its mid to late 80's is because it is really light.I t probably has thriple butted Chromoly tubing.  The frame does not have the original paint. My guess is Italian. If not perhaps Specialized.

Comment: Also the BB shell, especially any cutouts on the bottom. You also might have better luck over at the classic and vintage forum at bikeforums.net. There are a lot of vintage bike collectors there who can ID vintage steel frames very well.

Comment: Thank you guys for your input. I will go to the classic forum. Hope you are all well and safe.

Comment: Downtube shifters date it to probably the 80s, maybe late 70s.  Before that they used stem shifters, and after that they used handlebar shifters.  The crank style (not "cottered" and probably square crank end) indicates it's not earlier than the mid 70s.  Everything looks pretty standard for the era.

Comment: I hope you checked the inside for rust before painting it. A close inspection for cracks and deformations is also a good idea. This frame looks like it’s seen some things.

Comment: Sorry for the delay . Yes did get rid of all the surface rust . There were no cracks on it.  since then I did some with the BIke Forum guys, but nothing 100% is determined yet. The 2 closest frames to this one that came up are the Koga Miyata Pro race and the Medeci

Comment: https://2velo.com/koga-miyata-pro-racer-tange-champion-dura-ace-7200/

Comment: It has braze-ons for the shifters and bottle cage, but not for the rear brake cable. That should help date it.

Comment: @Dima When you do find more info, feel free to add it as an answer to your own question.  That's allowed and encouraged by SE.  Good luck - looks like a nice bike.

Comment: Thank you Criggie. I am really happy for joining this exchange.